# unable to access newly created domain in nginx on ubuntu

Tags: magento2, nginx, server-setup

recently was setting up Magento in my local system, I did installed MariaDB, nginx and php7.1.

I did created new files in sites-available and did symlink as well. And I did run nginx -t there were no error looks everything fine but when KI try the domain on browser, i can see a message which says site can't be reached.

Can any one help me what might be the issue.

Please find the site configuration details

```
upstream fastcgi_backend {
         server  unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;
    server_name  dev.magento.com;

    client_max_body_size 100M;
    set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/html/magento2;
    set $MAGE_MODE developer;
    include /var/www/html/magento2/nginx.conf.sample;
}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

open this file:

```
/etc/hosts
```

and add this line:

```
127.0.0.1 dev.magento.com
```

read error in your browser. it is trying to open this domain `dev.magento.com` but DNS record is missing. 
https://www.whatsmydns.net/#A/dev.magento.com

so you need to trick your browser to open this domain inside your own system.
either use `127.0.0.1` or any local ip address available in `ifconfig`.